# Ignore phone silence mode

Tags: java, android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building a security system for my office, which can be controlled via an android app. The app also should notify the user when an alarm is triggered by the security system. Therefore i'm using FCM push notications.

But how can i play a notification sound at full volume, even when the phone is in no-disturb or silence mode?

There is an app i used before, called "pushover", which lets our employees receive a push notification when the alarm has been triggered. They have a setting in their app "play high-priority notification sounds through alarm channel", which does that pretty well. But what does the "alarm channel" mean and how can i send notifications through it?

Answer (score 1):

THere's different streams of audio in Android.  One of those is the alarm stream.  That setting would use the ALARM channel for this sound.  This will not go through silence mode-  the alarm channel has a separate volume control from media, but is still set to 0 if all sounds are off.

And you wouldn't do this through a notification.  You'd do it through Java code in your app when the notification is received.  But there is no way to force a sound if the user is in silent mode.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I didn't think about the second way. What would be a way to do it? Listening to the notifications and then start a new mediaplayer, which plays the sound through the alarm stream? Sorry, i'm fairly new to native app development